# Solve $xyy'+x^2 + y^2=0$ for $y(1)=1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

It is asked to solve de ODE

$$xyy'+x^2 + y^2=0 ,y(1)=1$$

I know how to solve the ODE

$$y'=\frac{-(x^2+y^2)}{xy}, y(1)=1$$

but how should I deal with the case xy=0? The book resolution don't consider this case, so I am confuse. If $xy=0$, $y=0$ or $x=0$. If we substitute on the equation, we will see that y=0 $\iff$ x=0. What should I do with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the solution needs to be defined on an open interval (and in addition, this open interval must include 1). So your answer is right,on the interval $x$ in $(0,\infty)$. You may try to extend the solution to a bigger interval, but it is not guaranteed to exist. wolframalpha gives explicit solution $y=\frac{\sqrt{3-x^4}}{\sqrt2x}$, which obviously goes to $\infty$ as $x\to0^+$, of course then you need to argue without using wolfram alpha that the solution cannot be extended to a larger interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The case $xy = 0$ is excluded by your initial condition $y(1) = 1$. That is, if it were ever the case that $xy = 0$, then from the ODE, $x^2 + y^2 = 0 \Rightarrow x = y = 0$ identically.